# CentOS 6.x and jansson library problems

Tags: python, curl, centos, yum, shared-libraries

My OS is CentOS 6.4 x86_64bit.

And I was trying to use jansson lib just like what their tutorial shows.

Here is my history.

1. I downloaded github_commits.c
2. I downloaded curl lib.
3. I got some problem with libjansson.so.4
4. So I put 'ldconfig' and It seems like everything OK.
5. I need to yum update in some reason. so I command 'yum update'
6. terminal shows error below:

   There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
   required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pycurl.so: undefined symbol: CRYPTO_set_locking_callback

   Please install a package which provides this module, or
   verify that the module is installed correctly.

   It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
   current version of Python, which is:
   2.6.6 (r266:84292, Feb 22 2013, 00:00:18) 
   [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)]

   If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to 
   the yum faq at:
     http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
7. on internet I found solution which says I have to delete curl.
   this is link: http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=263887
8. So I got dilemma here. I have to use curl, because of jansson. at the same time,
   I also have to use yum

Is there any idea for this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use yum to install curl and curl-devel?

```
yum install curl

yum install curl-devel
```

Comment: Why not install using yum?

Comment: Actually I just recovered my system:( maybe your solution can work, but there's no way for such experiment.Thanks